# ¿Cómo evitar el fatal error del call to a member function execute()?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Muy buenas. Siguiendo el ejemplo en este enlace [Ejemplo con boton eliminar y editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81892/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-los-datos-del-formulario-en-ajax-y-php/)

Y casi lograba hasta que aparece un error lo que no me deja verificar o probar con la adaptación a mi base de datos, antes de proseguir con este problema, he visto muchos temas que solo afectan al php y diferentes errores que solo quedaron relacionadas con Php y mysqli, nunca con Ajax. Este es el error que aparece luego de proseguir para verificar el funcionamiento con `indexcafe.php`

[image: Fatal Error]

Luego de revisar en la línea, relaciona:

`Linea 120 :`

```html
$stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM compra_cafe");//Sentencia.   
 $stmt->execute(); //Ejecuta sentencia.
 $stmt->store_result();//Transfiere un conjunto de resulados de la última consulta.
```

Esto es lo que no comprendo en verdad, he investigado después de pensar en varias soluciones que me ha dejado pensado en todo el día, segun sé que en este código debería haber estado con `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` pero ya estaba añadida más rato despues de este código. Dejo los demás códigos para que puedan revisar, todo esta quedado bien, solo salvo que en `indexcafe.php` tiene este error de la línea.

**`indexcafe.php`**

```html
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="es-ES">
<!--<![end-if]-->
<head>
<!-- Jquery -> Libs -->    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Caracteres UTF-8 --> 
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Index Cafe</title><!-- 65 character (Limit 66 characters SEO) -->
 <style type="text/css">
  table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
   width: 100%
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  th, td {
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
 </style>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   //boton añadir
   $(".anadir").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    // alert(id);

    // Valores añadidos.
    var id_compra_cafe = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_compra_cafe').val();
    var id_cafe = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_cafe').val();
    var id_usuario = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_usuario').val();
    var precio = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.precio').val();
    var iva = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.iva').val();
    var total = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.total').val();

    $.post('control_cafe.php', {
     //variable caso anadir.
     Caso:'anadir',
     Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe,
     Id_cafe:id_cafe,
     Id_usuario:id_usuario,
     Precio:precio,
     IVA:iva,
     Total:total
    },function(e){
     alert(e);
    });     
   });

   //boton editar
   $(".editar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // alert(id);

    // Valores modificados.
    var precio = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.precio').val();
    var iva = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.iva').val();
    var total = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.total').val();

   $.post('control_cafe.php', {
     //variable caso editar.
     Caso:'editar',
     Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe,
     Id_cafe:id_cafe,
     Id_usuario:id_usuario,
     Precio:precio,
     IVA:iva,
     Total:total
    },function(e){
     alert(e);
    });     
   });

   // boton eliminar
   $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // alert (id);

    // Removiendo td tabla.
    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();

    $.post('control_cafe.php', {
     // Variable caso eliminar.
     Caso:'eliminar',
     Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe
    }, function(e){
     alert(e);
    });
   });

 }); // fin documento.
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

 require_once 'conexion2.php';

 //Obtengo datos desde MySQL
 $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM compra_cafe");//Sentencia.   
 $stmt->execute(); //Ejecuta sentencia.
 $stmt->store_result();//Transfiere un conjunto de resulados de la última consulta.
 if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>
  <table><tr><th>Id_compra_cafe</th>
       <th>Id_cafe</th>
       <th>Id_usuario</th>
       <th>Precio</th>
       <th>IVA</th>
       <th>Total</th>
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>";
  // Obteniendo resultado desde la BD.
  $stmt->bind_result($id_compra_cafe,$id_cafe,$id_usuario,$precio,$iva,$total);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   echo "
    <tr>
     <td><input type=hidden class='myid' value='$id_compra_cafe'/> $id_compra_cafe </td>
     <td><input type=text class=id_compra_cafe value='$id_compra_cafe' placeholder='Id_compra_cafe:'/></td>
     <td><input type=hidden class='myid' value='$id_cafe'/> $id_cafe </td>
     <td><input type=text class=id_cafe value='$Id_cafe' placeholder='Id_cafe:'/></td>
     <td><input type=hidden class='myid' value='$id_usuario'/> $id_usuario </td>
     <td><input type=text class=id_usuario value='$id_usuario' placeholder='Id_usuario:'/></td>
     <td><input type=text class=precio value='$precio' placeholder='Precio:' /></td>
     <td><input type=text class=iva value='$iva' placeholder='IVA:' /></td>
     <td><input type=text class=total value='$total' placeholder='Total:' /></td>
     <td><button class=anadir data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
      Anadir</button></td>
     <td><button class=editar data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
      Editar</button></td>
     <td><button class=eliminar data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
      Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
   ";
  } $stmt->close(); // cerrar sentencia.

  echo "

    </table>
   </div>

  ";

 } else {
  $stmt->close(); // cerrar sentencia.
  echo "<h3>No se ha encontrado ningun registro.</h3>";
 }
 $c->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**`conexion2.php`**

```html
<?php // estilo object orient mysqli
$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "prueba";

//creando conexión
$c = new mysqli($server, $usuario, $password, $db);

//revisando conexión
if ($c->connect_error) {
 die("Conexion fallada: " . $c->connect_error);
}

//Aplicar todo caracter al UTF-8 para MYSQL.
 if (!$c->set_charset("utf8")) {
     printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $c->error);
     exit();
 }
?>
```

**`control_cafe.php`**

```html
<?php 
$id_compra_cafe = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if($_POST['Caso']=='anadir') {
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'] ?: '';
 $precio = $_POST['precio'] ?: '';
 $iva = $_POST['iva'] ?: '';
 $total = $_POST['total'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 $stmt = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO compra_cafe(id_compra_cafe, id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("iiisss", $id_compra_cafe, $id_cafe, $id_usuario, $precio, $iva, $total);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 echo "Compra añadida existosa";
}

if ($_POST['Caso']=='editar') {
 // Obtener id desde el boton editar.
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'] ?: '';
 $precio = $_POST['precio'] ?: '';
 $iva = $_POST['iva'] ?: '';
 $total = $_POST['total'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 //Sentencia editar.
 $stmt = $c->prepare("UPDATE compra_cafe SET precio=?, iva=?, total=? WHERE id_compra_cafe=? AND id_cafe=? AND id_usuario=? LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->bind_param("sssiii",$precio,$iva,$total,$id_compra_cafe,$id_cafe,$id_usuario);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close(); // cierra sentencia.
 echo "La compra fue editada correctamente";
}

if ($_POST['Caso']=='eliminar') {
 // Obtener id desde el botón eliminar.
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 // sentencia eliminar.
 $stmt = $c->prepare("DELETE FROM compra_cafe WHERE id_compra_cafe=?");
 $stmt->bind_param("i",$id_compra_cafe);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close(); // cierra sentencia.
 echo "Compra eliminada";
}

?>
```

**`tabla compra_cafe`**

```html
CREATE TABLE `compra_cafe` (
 `id_compra_cafe` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_cafe` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Precio` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `IVA` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `Total` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_compra_cafe`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_cafe` (`id_cafe`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
 CONSTRAINT `compra_cafe_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cafe`) REFERENCES `tipo_cafe` (`id_cafe`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `compra_cafe_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`Id_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Y por último, en `indexcafe.php` donde debería dejar un espacio en blanco para poder añadir los registros de la tabla `compra_cafe` del base de datos `cafe`? Espero sus comentarios y soluciones al respecto!
Saludos!

Comment: primero que nada no es lo mismo el esta usandolo para actualizar la base de datos y tiene  $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$nombre,$apellidos,$correo,$id); lo cual no haces tu ...

Comment: o sea que debo descartar el bind_param del `control_cafe.php`? y que el `$stmt=$c->prepare(query)` se quedara conservado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error común: preparar una consulta ya preparada.

Esto quiere decir que **las consultas que no usan datos desde el exterior no tienen que ser preparadas**, puedes enviarlas sin problemas a la BD mediante el método **[`query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)**. Es decir, una consulta como esta: `SELECT * FROM compra_cafe` no necesita ninguna preparación.

Por otra parte, las consultas que sí usan datos desde el exteior, **deben ser preparadas** para evitar la inyección SQL. De modo que una consulta como esta: `SELECT * FROM compra_cafe WHERE id=?` sí necesita ser preparada, enviando el parámetro `id`, reemplazado en la cadena por `?`.

Algo más o menos así:

```
$stmt = $c->query("SELECT * FROM compra_cafe");//Sentencia.         
    // Esto no es necesario para consultas sin criterios $stmt->execute(); 

//Puedes verificar que no hay ningún problema con el $stmt
    if ($stmt)
    {  
        //Ejecuta sentencia.
        $stmt->store_result();//Transfiere un conjunto de resulados de la última consulta.
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Hubo un problema con la consulta";
    }
```

En este [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ebaf-pykd) tienes un ejemplo completo de una consulta sin parámetros externos.

Puedes ver también el [apartado III de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967).

Comment: Tienes razón, escribí con tu código y de ahi me dice que el stmt tiene problema con la consulta, y ahora justo me tira un fatal error, que era el $stmt->close(); (igual lo aparté) y de ahi me dice que no hay ningun registro, salvo que en la tabla si hay registros. Y lo más raro, no esta todos los datos, ni los botones que se debería haber mostrado el indexcafe

Comment: @Baku84 El Statement debe cerrarse dentro del bloque if que indica que el mismo ha devuelto TRUE, al final , una vez almacenados los resultados.

Comment: No lo comprendo, de hecho el stmt->close esta en tres ocasiones (el ultimo lo separé) no comprendo bien este código. aún sigo viendo los echos, no todos los formatos de los botones y los registros.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no comprendes ? Cada Statement es independiente . En el error planteado en tu pregunta el problema es el que te expliqué, es decir, no puedes usar `prepare` en una consulta que no recibirá posteriormente valores con `bind...`. Si hay otros errores en el código es cuestión de detectarlos y tratar de resolverlos. @Baku84

Comment: Al final se resolvio el problema, el problema venia del conexion2.php, que tenía que relacionar bien con el base de datos ($db = "prueba" a "cafe") y de ahi todo estaba bien, con pequeños arreglos del form, quedaba perfectamente. Aunque; al testear con los botones, nada pasa, nada de nada, debo empezar a hacer otra pregunta en esto? Saludos

Comment: @Baku84 Puedes **[formular una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)** explicando el problema que estás teniendo ahora y lo que has intentado para resolverlo. Saludos.

Comment: creo que ya formulé otra pregunta, gracias.