# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de un select con mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

La duda que tengo es bastante simple, quiero hacer una consulta del tipo:

`select nombre from jugadores`

Estoy intentando hacerla con los "**Prepared Statements**"  de **MySQLi**. No sé si es conveniente hacerlo así o no hace falta, por que no debo ligar ningún parámetro, dado que necesito TODOS los nombres.

Comment: En ese caso no necesitas usar prepared statements, ya que los mismos se usan para controlar los datos que vienen de fuera. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de consulta](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ebaf-pykd) usando mysqli sin ps. Puedes ver también [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82808/29967). Digamos que una consulta como `select nombre from jugadores` ya está preparada, no necesitas prepararla.

Comment: Gracias, ponlo en la respuesta, ya he comprobado que funciona.

Comment: Me alegra de lo hayas resuelto. Con la respuesta de @xerif es suficiente y está bien explicado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para consultas SELECT es  más eficiente realizar la consulta directamente en lugar de prepararla, si además la consulta es estática y no necesitas pasar ningún parámetro externo, no tendrás problemas de inyección SQL

Ejemplo :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}


/* consulta SELECT */
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT campo FROM mi_tabla")) {

    echo 'Número de resultados: '. $resultado->num_rows;

    /* recorrer los resultados  */
    while ( $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo $fila["campo"];
    }

}
```